# Is there a way to get the targetSdkVersion for both an embedded android library and its using app?

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

I've got an android library that is used by my app. The library provides a service to the app. Recently the app could not bind the service and after a while I found that the targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion of the app were higher than in my library. After I fixed that the binding worked again.
For the future I would like to give a warning if the versions do not match. So in my library I have to check, if the version of the calling app is too high.

Using this code I can get the compileSdkVersion of the calling app, but not of the library:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = appContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(appContext.getPackageName(), 0);
int targetSdkVersionUserApp = packageInfo.applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion;
```

How do I additionally get the version of the library? The service is not created, when I want to check the versions, so I do not have the correct context to look for the version.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "How do I additionally get the version of the library?" -- at runtime, there is no "version of the library". That sort of information gets used purely at compile-time.

Comment: So there is no way to compare both?

Comment: Not at runtime.